# What kind of power connector is this?

Tags: connector

I have a problem with determining the type of connector shown in the picture. The female plug looks like the Molex 5557 type. The dimensions of this plug confirm this. The problem is with the male socket - I can not find the right model. External dimensions suggest type Molex 5566, but the positioning of pins (centrally) and the lack of plastic pegs do not match. The pins in the connector are square, the side has a length of 1.15mm. In the back there are also letters "HXH".
[image: Unknown connector]

Comment: Looks like half of the atx 12V connector

Comment: Pin centers are most likely .156 inch.

Comment: Indeed, the pins have a spacing of 4.2 mm. I think this may be the JMC-4202WV-1 model. Unfortunately, I can not find more information on this topic. Maybe someone will know who is the manufacturer and what are the replacements for this connector.

Comment: Looks like I've found right model - it's C4255 series, model C4255WV. Are there any replacements for this model?